# Problem with using PyGenStability after it was installed succesfully

Tags: python

Hi
I have installed PyGenStability (https://github.com/barahona-research-group/PyGenStability/) in my Mac Pro successfully. However, when I wanted to import the code (from pygenstability import run, plotting) it give the error as bellow. Would you please advise me how to fix this? Many thanks, best, Meghdad

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 3
      1 import networkx as nx
----> 3 from pygenstability import run, plotting
      5 import create_graph

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pygenstability/__init__.py:4
      2 from pygenstability.io import load_results
      3 from pygenstability.io import save_results
----> 4 from pygenstability.pygenstability import run

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pygenstability/pygenstability.py:31
     28 from tqdm import tqdm
     30 from pygenstability import generalized_louvain
---> 31 from pygenstability.constructors import load_constructor
     32 from pygenstability.io import save_results
     33 from pygenstability.optimal_scales import identify_optimal_scales

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pygenstability/constructors.py:130
    126     def _get_data(self, scale):
    127         """Method to be defined in child classes for get_data."""
--> 130 class constructor_linearized(Constructor):
    131     r"""Constructor for continuous linearized Markov Stability.
    132 
    133     The quality matrix is:
   (...)
    139     and the associated null model is :math:`v_1=v_2=\frac{d}{2M}`.
    140     """
    142     @_limit_numpy
    143     def prepare(self, **kwargs):

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pygenstability/constructors.py:143, in constructor_linearized()
    130 class constructor_linearized(Constructor):
    131     r"""Constructor for continuous linearized Markov Stability.
    132 
    133     The quality matrix is:
   (...)
    139     and the associated null model is :math:`v_1=v_2=\frac{d}{2M}`.
    140     """
    142     @_limit_numpy
--> 143     def prepare(self, **kwargs):
    144         """Prepare the constructor with non-scale dependent computations."""
    145         degrees = np.array(self.graph.sum(1)).flatten()

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pygenstability/constructors.py:47, in _limit_numpy(f)
     44 def _limit_numpy(f):
     45     """Wrapper to limit threads used by numpy."""
---> 47     @threadpool_limits.wrap(limits=1, user_api="blas")
     48     @threadpool_limits.wrap(limits=1, user_api="openmp")
     49     def limit(*args, **kwargs):
     50         return f(*args, **kwargs)
     52     return limit

AttributeError: type object 'threadpool_limits' has no attribute 'wrap'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```